# How do I make a class module with one or more functions in Visual C++ 2008 Managed

Tags: class, function, visual-c++, clr, managed

I am an absolute novice in Visual C++ and hence I have to ask you, how would I create a managed class module (new class) with one or more functions inside of my managed C++ project (Visual Studio 2008)?
How would I call the method of the class for example if a button was pressed. I was unable to understand the very complicated tutorials on it and most of the tutorials referring to unmanaged code or older versions of visual studio. My own attempt totally failed and produced only errors, since I found no right options on how I would add a new class file to my Visual C++ managed project. If I choose a new "CLR Component Class" I get a warning message telling me about components filling the right pane of my screen. If I choose a new "CLR Windows Form Class" it happens just nothing, no file with the extension ".class" would be added or I do not know the file which was newly added. I just need a very basic class file with one public function in it which I would be able to call from any location of my project.

I have a very big main() cpp-file already (main.cpp) with lots of functions in it.
There are about thousand functions or more, so it becomes difficult to search or scroll.
Now I would like to put some of these 1000 functions in a second cpp-file within my current project (in Visual Basic 6 it was simply called a 'new module' in CSharp it is called a 'new class file').
The problem is, that I can't call this functions in Visual C++, once I have moved them out of my
main.cpp to module1.cpp for example.

That's what I don't want:

- a DLL
- a second project
- adding a reference to something (in project/references)
- double declarations

I know there is a way to make just a simple class and then create a new object of this class to use its methods. That's what I want. The examples in Google on this did not work for me, because they were for earlier versions of visual studio and not compatible with my version. From this examples I know what I want, but I haven't got the knowledge to implement it in Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to try again to post step-by-step instructions on how to add a class file to a VS2008 WinForm project. **I again did not realize until completing the list that numbered items don't always work cleanly here. I was able to fix all but one of the numbers, so this should be good to go - David W**

1. These steps assume a simple starting project in VS2008, consisting of a WinForms app with a default form and a single button control, as illustrated here:
   [image: Starting point of demo project.]
2. To add a new class to this project, right-click on "DemoWinFormApp," select "Add," then select "Class..." as shown below:
   [image: Add a class]
3. Give the class a name, DemoNewClass, in the "Name" field of the "Add Class" dialog, and click the "Add" button:
   [image: Add new class name]
4. Visual Studio will add two files to your project: DemoNewClass.h, the header file for definitions, and DemoNewClass.cpp for the actual C++ implementation of the functions defined in the header. Once added, the Visual Studio editor makes the header file active, but displays the following:
   [image: Editor message after header file added]
   Click the "click here to switch to code view" link to open the source editor.
5. The editor now displays the source of the DemoNewClass.h header file. This file includes an automatic declaration of the namespace from the main application, DemoWinFormApp, and also contains the two default constructors in the "public:" region, which we will not touch. We will add a new public static method to DemoNewClass immediately after the second constructor definition.
6. We will add a *static* method - one that does not require instantiation of the host class - that puts asterisks around a String. The method will be called "DecorateString"
7. Immediately following the second constructor, add the declaration as illustrated here and highlighted in blue:
   [image: New function declaration]
8. With the declaration in place, we must now add the implementation. In Solution Explorer, double-click on "DemoNewClass.cpp" to edit the file:
   [image: Editing implementation file]
9. The editor window opens, and the file has only two lines - two *include* directives that instruct the compiler to bring in the referenced files as part of the current source. The declaration provided in DemoNewClass.h is provided by default.
10. Add the implementation of the DecorateString method to the .cpp file as shown here:
    [image]
    This completes the definition of the new class, the DecorateString declaration, and the provision of the implementation for the DecorateString method. All that remains now is to allow the WinForms app to reference the class and method from the main form.
11. From the Solution Explorer, double-click the "Form1.h" file in the "Header Files" list of the DemoWinFormApp project, which brings up Form1 in the editor. (The button was already added, and the steps to add the button are left to the reader):
    [image]
12. To demonstrate the new class method, we'll have the button click display a string modified by our DecorateString method via the MessageBox class. First, we must make the form aware of our new class by supplying an include directive to the new class' header at the top of the Form1.h header file. Right-click on the form in the designer, and click "View Code.." to bring up the source editor
    [image]
13. To make the class and its methods available to the form, we must supply an *include* directive for the class' header, DemoNewClass.h, near the top of the Form1.cpp implementation source file:
    [image: Include directive]
14. From Solution Explorer, double-click on "Form1.h" to open the Form Designer with Form1. Alternatively, if the file is still open in the editor, you could open the Designer by clicking the editor tab labled "Form1.h [Design]"
15. We will call our new class method from the event handler tied to the "button1" button on the form. Visual Studio provides a default handler by double-clicking "button1" in the designer:
    [image: button click handler]
16. Type the code to invoke the MessageBox::Show method, passing as a parameter a string modified by the DemoNewClass::DecorateString method, as follows - noting how Intellisense is aware of our new class along the way:
    [image]
17. And here's the completed event handler/class method call:
    [image: complete method call]
18. From the Visual Studio "Build" menu, select "Build Solution" (or press F6). This will compile the solution and reveal any syntax errors that may have been detected. The sample, as provided, compiles and builds cleanly.

[image: Build solution...]

[image]
20. With a successful build, all that remains is to test the application. Press F5 to run the application and display the test form:

[image]

21. Click "button1" to run the handler, and see the decorated string:

[image]

The passed parameter, "foo", was successfully passed to the new class' DecorateString method, and returned to the MessageBox method for display. The new class method declaration and form reference are now complete.

Good luck.

Comment: Great! I'm glad this was helpful for you!

Answer (score 2):

**Note: I wrestled considerably with the MarkDown editor to ensure code blocks and numbered steps were formatted correctly, but for some reason a few elements remain subbornly incorrect. I will attempt to fix on a later post. For now, I opted to get the requested information in at least some form posted for you.

Using Visual Studio 2008 as a baseline tool, follow these steps:

1. Select "File->New Project"
2. From the "Project Types" list of the "New Project" dialog, beneath "Visual C++" under "Other Languages," click "CLR."
3. From the "Visual Studio Installed Templates" list, click "Class Library"
4. In the Name box in the lower half of the "New Project" dialog, supply a name for your project. For the example, use "SampleCPPAssembly"
5. Visual Studio 2008 will have created a "shell" class and header files named to match the project, eg SampleCPPAssembly.h and SampleCPPAssembly.cpp
6. Open "SampleCPPAssembly.h"
7. Change the name of the class to "public ref class SampleClass"
8. Inside the opening curly brace, add a text line saying "public:". This defines the section containing public methods of the class.
9. Beneath the "public:" declaration, insert the following:

```
   
    static String ^ DecorateString(String ^ foo);
```

10. Save the file.

11. Open "SampleCPPAssembly.cpp" by double-clicking on it from the Solution Explorer.
12. Within the curly-brackets following "namespace SampleCPPAssembly", insert the following:

```
    
    String ^ SampleClass::DecorateString(String ^ foo){
        return gcnew String("*"+foo+"*");
    }
```

13. Save the file.

14. From the Build menu, select "Build Solution."
15. If the project does build successfully, re-check steps 1-12 for any possible errors.

This completes construction of the C++ CLR assembly. We now work to create a simple console application that exercises the method.

1. In "Solution Explorer," from the same solution, right-click, and select "Add->New Project"
2. From the "Add New Project dialog," beneath "Visual C++" under the "Other Languages" entry, select "CLR"
3. From the "Visual Studio Installed Templates," select "CLR Console Application."
4. In the "Name" box near the bottom of the "Add New Project" dialog, type "ConsumeSampleAssembly"
5. Click OK.
6. In "Solution Explorer," right-click the "ConsumeSampleAssembly" project, and select "Properties."
7. In the Property Pages dialog, single-click the "Framework and References" entry beenath the "Common Properties" header.
8. In the middle of the dialog, click the "Add New Reference..." button.
9. From the "Add Reference" dialog, click to select the "Projects" tab.
10. From the Project list, click to select "SampleCPPAssembly"
11. Click OK to close the "Add Reference" dialog.
12. Click OK to close the Property Page dialog.
13. Under the "Source Files" folder beneath the newly-created "ConsumeSampleAssembly" project, double-click on the "ConsumeSampleAssembly.cpp" source file.
14. Immediately beneath "using namespace System;", add the following line:

```
    
    using namespace SampleCPPAssembly;
```

15. Eliminate the existing code between the curly braces following "int main(...)". (Do not *delete* the curly braces.

16. Replace the content within the curly braces with the following:

```
   
    Console::WriteLine(SampleClass::DecorateString(L"Hello"));
    return 0;
```

17. Save the source file.

18. In the editor, just inside the left boundary, along the source line containing "return 0;", click to set a breakpoint. This causes the debugger to stop here when the application runs and allows you to see the results of the application. Without the breakpoint, the application will start and finish too rapidly to be observed.

19. Within the Solution Explorer, right click on the "ConsumeSampleAssembly" project, and select "Set as Startup Project."

19. Press F5 to compile and run the project.

20. You should observe a console window with the output of "*Hello*".

Summary: You've created a C++ CLR assembly containing a single method, DecorateString, which accepts a string as a parameter and returns that string surrounded by asterisks. You've then created a simple C++ CLR console application, added a project reference to the new assembly, then called the DecorateString method from the "main(..)" method with a value of "Hello", which is modified by the method to be returned as "*Hello*". This demonstrates that your CLR console app is successfully calling the C++ CLR assembly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're wanting. The illustration above creates an example "standalone" assembly with a single class file - if you don't need or want the entire separate assembly, just right-click on your existing presumably CLR-based project, select "Add..", then select "Class.." From the "Add Class" dialog, select "CLR," and select "Component Class". Provide a name for the class, the definition in the corresponding header (.h) file (where your method declaration would reside), and the method implementation in the source (.cpp) file. The class/method should be available in your project.

Comment: Re-read my previous reply. I described specifically the steps to take *to add a class file to your existing project*, not as an external DLL. From Solution Explorer, right-click on your *existing* project, select "Add...," then select "Class...". That brings up the Add Class dialog I mentioned in my previous reply, where you need to select "CLR Component Class" as the type of class to add. You need only provide a name for the class, and no DLL is involved. You then provide the declarations in the header (.h) file, and the implementation in the .cpp file. Can you get at least that far?

Comment: Based on your last post, it sounds like you're close. Add the *declaration* of the function *immediately* below the public: section of the header, and the implementation portion in the .cpp file for your added class. The error you posted re the code in the public section suggests you may have inadvertently added it outside the public declaration region.

Comment: The console app doesn't matter; the concept is the same. All we are doing is  adding a class to a project. This really is how to do it. It isn't that complicated. What happened when you tried this time?

Comment: At this point, I think you're going to have to post your code. I have no way of knowing what kind of errant artifacts may now be present that must be overcome to resolve the problem.

Comment: In reviewing your comments, two things occurred to me. First, when you talked about the "blue screen" after adding the "Component Class," you need to click the link that says "click here to switch to code view." Second, in the .cpp file of your main form, add an include directive to your new class' header file, eg #include "MyNewClassName.h" I've reviewed the basic steps outlined here against a WinForms project and verified that the concepts outlined are sound. We must remove errant elements of your intervening attempts before going further, however.

Comment: Finally, please understand that the basic steps I've outlined - adding a new "Component Class" from the Project->Add->Class menu option from Solution Explorer, *is* the way to add a new class to your project. You  provide function headers in the .h file, and implementation in the .cpp file. You then add #include directives to reference the new class' header file in the project's other .cpp files that need to call the new class' functions. Lastly, please understand that C++ is *not* VB6.